# java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet

Tags: java, oracle

I hava java swing project which is developed in JBuilder IDE. Now I need to transfer the project in to NetBeans. But when I do that following exception is thrown.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1184591038813385495, local class serialVersionUID = -6778266293933460977
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
```

This is where the exception occurs

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
      ObjectInputStream istream       = new  ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

      try{

        crset = (OracleCachedRowSet) istream.readObject();
}
```

But if works fine in the Jbuilder. I used following jars for the project

```
ocrs12.zip
ojdbc14.jar.zip
ORADriver.jar
classes12.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-pool-1.5.2.jar
jcommon-1.0.8.jar
jfreechart-1.0.4.jar
xerces.jar
```

Can some one help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Who/which process serializes OracleCachedRowSet in the first place? The version of the class is different there than it is in the process that is deserializing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when you try to deserialize an object with a different version of the class than it was serialized with (ie you have different versions of the oracle driver loaded).

Any idea why an OracleCachedRowSet is being serialized (and where)? That doesn't seem desirable.

Comment: I have used same jars which are using in the Jbuilder. Only project is developed using JDK 1.4 in the Jbuilder and I used 1.6 in NetBeans. Also project is build without any case in the NetBeans. So I create a exe of it and it works fine. I think the problem with the netbens. any idea???

Comment: I'd find out why it's being serialized in the first place.  Whatever you're deserializing, needs to be serialized from the same JDK version.

Comment: I tried that by changing the jdk version used by netbeans. But still problem is there. :(

Comment: Finaly I able to solve the problem. I did both the object serialization and deserialization with JDK 1.6 . Then the project works fine. Thanks for your help Dmitri.. :)

Comment: I'd still recommend against using serialization this way, for this reason.